# Response.WriteFile stopping previous request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button that calls a click event to download a picture. In my click event I have some code to change my display as the Save dialog pops up. The issue I am having is that when the dialog comes up it stops the previous line of code from executing. How can I check to see that my code has executed before calling the function?

Here is my button event handler and function:

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var _title          = txtTitle.Text;
    txtTitle.Text       = string.Empty;
    txtDescription.Text = string.Empty;

    ChangeDisplay();

    if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE")
        lblSnapShot.Visible = (lblSnapShot.Visible) ? false : true;

    SaveSnapShot(_title);
}

void SaveSnapShot(string _title)
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo _fileToDownload = new FileInfo(_path);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + _title + ".png\"");
        Response.WriteFile(_fileToDownload.FullName);

        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        ChangeDisplay();

        if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE")
            lblSnapShot.Visible = (lblSnapShot.Visible) ? false : true;

        Response.Write("SAVE FAILED \n Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: the only `response.write` I see is when the "Save Failed". Can you explain your question a little more.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring  I apologize for the vagueness of question.The title of my question should have been Response.WriteFile. In the click event the all of the code prior to the function call SaveSnapShot(); is not executed. It appears that the Response.WriteFile stops the processing of that code. If I comment out the function call, all of the code in the click event is executed.

Comment: and Response.End() has the same problem as CompleteRequest()?

Comment: Yes Response.End() has the same problem.

Comment: have you tried adding a Response.Flush() immediately before CompleteRequest?

Comment: Instead of Response.Write, is it possible to write your error message to a control (like a label) on the page that serves this image delivery function?

Comment: @hova Tried that, still doesn't work. I have been wrestling with this for a while now and have gotten really fed up with it. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @MadMAxJr The problem is, I am not getting an error. As a matter of fact there is no exception thrown. The code in the click event just before I call the function is not executing. The way I'm delivering the error is a none issue.

Answer (score 2):

Response.WriteFile doesn't stop the processing of the other code (that code comes before you even call WriteFile so how could it?)

However, your SaveSnapshot method is sending back to the browser an image instead of the usual response of HTML.  For each request from the browser, you can only send one response - you can't send back an image file and update HTML at the same time.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but when I comment out the call the other code processes just fine.

Comment: correct.  normally, ASP.NET will generate and send back HTML.  when you call Response.WriteFile, you are overriding that and telling ASP.NET to send back a file instead.  you need to get the user's browser (via javascript) to make a seperate request to your web app and in the seperate request is where you would call Response.WriteFile.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me an example of making a separate request. I hope I'm not asking a dumb question. I've been fighting with this for a while and my brain is a at a low functioning rate right now.